# Can we import one target into another target in IOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I am trying to call some functions of the Main app from the Notification Extension in the IOS app. To minimize the code changes, I am trying to import Notification Extension in the main app itself but I am getting an Undefined Symbol error in the main app.

Comment: It's likely that you want to create a shared module that both import from

Comment: @jnpdx
Is it possible that I dont create a module but directly import the Extension to main project . 
Example: import Extension

Comment: I can't think of a way, although it certainly may be possible. It isn't a good idea from a code organization perspective, in my opinion, though